# Validate date from other bounded context

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have two Bounded Context (studentenrollment, courses).
Studentenrollment has all the student with his course ids and his homework.
Courses have the admin part that content all the information related with the course.
When a student want to get information of the course, it hits an endpoint( /courses/ID) sending the jwt token. In the course context I get the student ID, course ID and create query that it's dispatched in the bus. In the query handler before getting the information of the course from the course ID, I want to validate if the student ID exist and this student has this course. For that I have to call the another context bounded studentenrollment. So, I was looking for how to handle that on internet and I found this:
https://medium.com/@martinezdelariva/authentication-and-authorization-in-ddd-671f7a5596ac

```
class findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQueryHandler()
    {
        public function handle($findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery)
        {
            $courseId = $findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery->courseId();
            $studentId = $findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery->studentId();

            $student = $this->collaboratorService->studentFrom(
                $courseId,
                $studentId
            );


            $this->courseRepository->findByCourseId($courseId);
        }
    }

    class collaboratorService()
    {
        public function studentFrom($courseId, $studentId)
        {
            $student = $this->studentEnrollmentClient->getStudentFrom($courseId, $studentId);

            if (!$student) {
                throw new InvalidStudentException();
            }

            return $student;
        }
    }
```

What do you think?

**UPDATED**

```
namespace App\Context\Course\Module\Course\UI\Controller;

class GetCourseController extends Controller
{
    public function getAction($request) {
        $this->ask(new FindByCourseIdQueryHandler($request->get('course_id'));
    }
}

namespace App\Context\Course\Module\Course\Infrastracture\Query;

class AuthorizedQueryDispatcher extends QueryDispatcher
{
    //In this case $query would be FindByCourseIdQueryHandler
    public function handle($query)
    {
        $authUser = $this->oauthService->getAuthUser();

        //it can be student or teacher
        $role = $authUser->getRole();
        $userId = $authUser->getUserId();

        //it will return FindByCourseIdAndStudentIdAuthorizedQueryHandler
        $authorizedQuery = $this->inflector->getAuthorizedQueryName->from($userId, $role, $query);

        $this->dispatch($authorizedQuery);

        $this->queryDispatch->dispatch($query);
    }
}

namespace App\Context\Course\Module\Course\Application\Query;

class FindByCourseIdAndStudentIdAuthorizedQueryHandler
{
    public function handle($findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery)
    {
        $student = $this->studentEnrollmentClient->getStudentFrom($findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery->courseId, $findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQuery->studentId);

        if (!$student) {
            throw new InvalidStudentException();
        }
    }
}

namespace App\Context\Course\Module\Course\Application\Query;

class findByCourseIdAndStudentIdQueryHandler()
{
    public function handle($findByCourseIdQueryHandler)
    {
        $courseId = $findByCourseIdQueryHandler->courseId();

        $this->courseRepository->findByCourseId($courseId);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you have an authorization modeling question, am I right?

Comment: Not really, I'm handle the authorization with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. It has some listener before executing the controller that recovery the token from the header and create an userAuth from the token. Then in the controller I get the student id from userAuth and set it in the query. My question is: if is good to use the collaboratorService to retrieve the student that belong to another bounded context. Because what i understood is that collaboratorService is for authorization. But in my case I'm using it to retrieve a student.

Comment: authorization not authentication, they are not the same.

Comment: I'm trying to see what kind of problem you have so I can give you a correct answer

Comment: the problem I have is that I need to know if that student has the course to allow him get the information of the course. But the relation between student and course is in the other bounded context (studentenrollment). So I put the logic inside of collaboratorService.

Comment: It's OK to cross BC boundaries to authorize, however, authorization should be clearly decoupled by the Domain layer and the dependency inversed.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Authorization should be clearly separated from the Domain layer, for example in a different package/namespace/module. Also, the dependency from the Domain to the Authorization should be inverted, the Domain should not depend/know about the authorization/

One way to implement it is to create an Authorization service, for example `FindByCourseIdAndStudentIdQueryAuthorizer` (let's name it Authorizer). This service may cross Bounded context (BC) boundaries, i.e. it could depend on remote domain services from remote BCs. Ideally, the remote data should be already available when the Authorizer does the checking. In this way the system is more resilient in case remote Bounded context services are not available. You can do this by listening to remote events or by background tasks.

Ideally, the domain layer (from any BC) should not know about the Authorizers.

One way to do this is to decorate the QueryDispatcher (or what you have) in the Composition root of the application with an AuthorizedQueryDispatcher. This AuthorizedQueryDispatcher, when it receives a query, it first *search* an Authorizer and then calls it. If the authorization fails then the query is rejected. If the authorization succedds or there is not authorizer then the query is sent to the real/decorated QueryDispatcher.

If can't do this (i.e. you don't have a QueryDispatcher) then you can try to decorate every query handler (by hand?). For example, you could have a `FindByCourseIdAndStudentIdAuthorizedQueryHandler` that has the same interface as the `FindByCourseIdAndStudentIdQueryHandler`. You could replace them in the composition root of the application (DIC).

Comment: I updated my question according to what you said, is it ok? take a look at the namesapce

Comment: @AgustinCastro yes, but I would somehow use more abstraction, like the decorator patter

Comment: in which part should I use more abstraction?

Comment: @AgustinCastro for example I would decorate the QueueHandler